# Azure Durable - The binding types are not registered

Tags: .net-standard, azure-durable-functions

I am new to azure durable function. I wrote a small POC application and till yesterday everything was working fine. Today when I try to run, I am getting the error "The binding types are not registered". Does anyone have any idea on this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was fixed after upgrading Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask from 1.5.0 to 1.6.0 and Microsoft.Net.Sdk.Functions from 1.16 to 1.19.

Although the above solution fixed the issue. I am still trying to understand the reason behind this as the same code was working yesterday and the only change happened was that in the morning the IT team added a product license to my VS2017. 
My colleague is still using the old version of SDK and Durable libs and its working perfectly on his laptop.